# Is it possible to write javascript with Java in a jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

If I had code similar to the following, could I run it without any issues? I assume the Java will be run before the javascript, so the javascript won't have issues, but I haven't done this before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% functThatOutputsJavascript() %>
</script>
```

Comment: you should be able to write the javascript to the output writer. But I would recommend a different approach.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Of course it is. A JSP is just a template. You can put whatever you want in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very, very bad programming style, but yes, it is possible.

The code I am working on now has done some very similar stuff. I think you would actually want to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= functThatOutputsJavascript() %>
</script>
```

And actually, you can do even worse, using Java conditionals to modify the Javascript output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    while (i > 0) {
        <% if (serverVar)) { %>
            console.log("Server says yes!");
        <% } else { %>
            console.log("Server says no!");
        <% } %>
    }
</script>
```

This would then output this code if serverVar is true:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    while (i > 0) {
            console.log("Server says yes!");
    }
</script>
```

or this code if it is false:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    while (i > 0) {
            console.log("Server says no!");
    }
</script>
```

This is horrible coding style, and I hope you won't do it in practice! If you are wondering how to avoid writing code like this, check out this question: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

A general suggestion would be to use JSP EL (JSP Expression Language) to set server side variables into your Javascript, and then write all of your logic in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't even started writing anything yet (which is why I asked), so I'll look into avoiding this style. I might use it to temporarily get something working.

Comment: The use-cases where you would need this should be very, very slim. It would be MUCH better to use the JSP Expression language to get the results you want.